# Decrease Space between Columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have checked around other questions but I cant able to decrease the space between different columns of bootstrap in single row. I want my 4 divs that are in one row using Bootstrap classes but the space between these 4 divs is large which I don't want. Whereas I also used container it decreased the space a little but still there's way too much.
[Spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNy8v.png)

```css
body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-image: url('Main backgrounds/cool-background\ \(1\).png');
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100%;
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .heading{
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .boxesText{
            color: white;
        }
        .b1{
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: aqua;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            
        }
        i{
            font-size: 45px;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            /*TO MIDDLE AN ELEMENT IN DIV FROM ALL SIDES*/
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            /* margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; */
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
            filter: drop-shadow(-5px 10px 7px #222);
        }
        .spacer{
            height: 6px;
        }
        .notification .badge {
            position: absolute;
            top: -10px;
            right: -10px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center boxesText">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-comment" style="margin-top: -4px; margin-left: 2px;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Discuss</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Booking</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-edit" style="margin-left: 4px;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Invoice</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Settings</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS please

Comment: Edited the snippet you can have a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!-- you can also resize the size of col-md-10 as of your need  -->
    <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <div class="row text-center boxesText">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="b1">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
                <span>Discuss</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="b1">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
                <span>Discuss</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="b1">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
                <span>Discuss</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="b1">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
                <span>Discuss</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate that is the exact thing i was wanting

Comment: can you please explain how that worked? I mean you have used enclosed all the divs in a col div and I think that was the reason it worked.

Comment: I didn't get it what are you saying. Please help me with what are you asking for

Comment: I am asking can you please explain what have you added to make it work. As it's working perfectly fine for me and I want to know how it worked.

Comment: I simply added class of bootstrap after row  <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto"> you can also resize size of col-md-10 as per your space requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No additional CSS is required but it is possible that you already added CSS and that makes it very easy to confuse Bootstrap.

what might work best is to add a `gutter`s to the **parent div** of all the columns which have an icon in them.

```
<div class="row text-center boxesText g-1">
```

Above, I added `g-1`. That is gutter size 1. You can use up to `g-5` and even `g-0` for no gutters.

If it turns out that actually you only wanted left and right guttering or you only wanted vertical guttering then try these instead.

```
gx-*  Horizontal gutter only
gy-*  Vertical gutter only
```

Worth noting, you would still have to fill up the columns as much as possible. Right now your icons are the only content, these will stay the same size no matter how you shape the columns and gutters.

Worth also noting, there seems to a missing closing `</div>` in your example above.

**Here is an alternative answer....**

Put it all inside 1 column and then use `justify-content-evenly`. This requires `d-flex` on that 1 column.

If this suggestion doesn't quite work try `justify-content-between` instead.

Please note that every instance of `b1`, `spacer` and `span` are now housed together in a containing div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center boxesText">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-evenly">

         <div>
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-comment" style="margin-top: -4px; margin-left: 2px;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Discuss</span>
         </div>

         <div>
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Booking</span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-edit" style="margin-left: 4px;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Invoice</span>
          </div>

         <div>
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Settings</span>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have applied the changes you suggested and by putting g-1 or g-0 it decrease the space but its not noticeable.

Comment: So I think what's happening there is like I said above, you can spend all day changing the column shape but in the end those icons are all the same size. to the naked eye nothing really changes. This might not make much of a difference but you can make those icons bigger. For font-awesome icons only..... add `fa-3x` to the class for each icon. This will help fill up the columns but it might not be a perfect solution.

Comment: Hi @RANA I've edited my answer to offer a second suggestion. Give that a try instead. The CSS for your inner divs and icons might be messing about with things. I would remove all the CSS for anything inside columns, try the above and then add CSS again if you need to.

Comment: It has worked but the space has removed totally cant able to add space between them tried with paddings and adding div tags and giving them width. Secondly there would be responsivity issue with it.

EDIT: Well i have now tried with removing container div its now a little better

Comment: On my second idea?? By the way, what does the `spacer` div do? If it just adding a little space between the icon and the span, could perhaps get rid of it and add bottom padding to `b1` div instead? In your HTML (with Bootstrap only) you can add `pb-1` to the `class="b1"` so it will be `class="b1 pb-1"`.

Comment: yup your second idea. Yes spacer is for space adding between span and div i used it as i cant bale to get the space with pb that's why added it

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code, check it, I believe this is the result you are looking for.

```css
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url('Main backgrounds/cool-background\ \(1\).png');
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 overflow-x: hidden;
 background: #7bc8f8;
        }

.row.text-center.boxesText {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.boxesText {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-3 {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
        
.b1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: aqua;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
 
.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
        
.heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.fa {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row text-center boxesText">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Discuss</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span>Booking</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Invoice</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="b1">
                <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Settings</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the space has decreased which was the major issue if I can change it according to my need and if its responsive then it would be the same thing that I need. But the text is in the box which I don't need and the divs I want them to be box shape I have used your code and it appears to be in rectangular form due to i think that you have used whole column as background.

Comment: Can you check if it's the way you wanted it? If the result is correct, to modify the space you indicated in the image you can change margin-left and margin-right of the selector .col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-3

Comment: Its better I have used your code but the issue is the same that its showing in the form of rectangles and I want them to be in square shaped boxes and i think its due to not limiting the width and height in b1 class. However i have also tried limiting the width and height but it gets distorted and i cant able to adjust them to center and the space between them is still large.

Comment: In the example I updated, the squares of the icons remain square and never become rectangular. Maybe something changes when you apply it to your site.